# Bayesian Lasso using PyMC3

Tags: linear-regression, bayesian, pymc, pymc3

I'm trying to reproduce the results of this [tutorial](http://www.austinrochford.com/posts/2013-09-02-prior-distributions-for-bayesian-regression-using-pymc.htm) (see LASSO regression) on PyMC3. As commented on this reddit [thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/2uglzd/prior_distributions_for_bayesian_regression_using/), the mixing for the first two coefficients wasn't good because the variables are correlated.

I tried implementing it in PyMC3 but it didn't work as expected when using Hamiltonian samplers. I could only get it working with the Metropolis sampler, which achieves the same result as PyMC2.

I don't know if it's something related to the fact that the Laplacian is peaked (discontinuous derivative at 0), but it worked perfectly well with Gaussian priors. I tried with or without MAP initialization and the result is always the same.

Here is my code:

```
from pymc import *
from scipy.stats import norm
import pylab as plt

# Same model as the tutorial 
n = 1000

x1 = norm.rvs(0, 1, size=n)
x2 = -x1 + norm.rvs(0, 10**-3, size=n)
x3 = norm.rvs(0, 1, size=n)

y = 10 * x1 + 10 * x2 + 0.1 * x3

with Model() as model:
    # Laplacian prior only works with Metropolis sampler
    coef1 = Laplace('x1', 0, b=1/sqrt(2))
    coef2 = Laplace('x2', 0, b=1/sqrt(2))
    coef3 = Laplace('x3', 0, b=1/sqrt(2))

    # Gaussian prior works with NUTS sampler
    #coef1 = Normal('x1', mu = 0, sd = 1)
    #coef2 = Normal('x2', mu = 0, sd = 1)
    #coef3 = Normal('x3', mu = 0, sd = 1)

    likelihood = Normal('y', mu= coef1 * x1 + coef2 * x2 + coef3 * x3, tau = 1, observed=y)

    #step = Metropolis() # Works just like PyMC2
    start = find_MAP() # Doesn't help
    step = NUTS(state = start) # Doesn't work
    trace = sample(10000, step, start = start, progressbar=True) 

plt.figure(figsize=(7, 7))
traceplot(trace)
plt.tight_layout()

autocorrplot(trace)
summary(trace)
```

Here is the error I get:

```
PositiveDefiniteError: Simple check failed. Diagonal contains negatives
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the NUTS sampler not supposed to work on cases like this?

Comment: I went ahead and rewrote the model into Stan. It doesn't break, but it does take an extremely long time to run NUTS. I suspect that since the model does not incorporate the fact that x1 ~= -x2, there are just an incredible number of rejections. So to answer your question: I don't believe NUTS should work on this case.

Comment: Does `Laplacian` make it Lasso?

Comment: @O.rka Lasso is the Maximum a Posteriori (MAP) solution of a linear model with normal likelihood and Laplacian prior. If instead of MAP you do Bayesian inference, it is not exactly Lasso, but it is related. See this article for more information: http://www.stat.ufl.edu/archived/casella/Papers/Lasso.pdf

Comment: The tutorial you referenced seems to have moved to http://austinrochford.com/posts/2013-09-02-prior-distributions-for-bayesian-regression-using-pymc.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whyking from the reddit thread gave the suggestion to use the MAP as scaling instead of the state and it actually worked wonders.

Here is a [notebook](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.githubusercontent.com/tabacof/8cba9680b11eb28455cf/raw/8c94990c744340520889fb11b9d9cf90fcf5bf72/notebook.ipynb) with the results and the updated [code](https://gist.github.com/tabacof/8cba9680b11eb28455cf).